# Unique formatting for div inside other div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a linked container that has an image, header, and text. The entire container should be clickable, but on hover, I only want the header to underline, not the text.

For example:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer
}

a:hover,a:active,a:focus {
  text-decoration: underline
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="spalink" title="">
        <div class="link-container">
            <div class="link-image" style="background-image: url(IMAGE);"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="link-content">
            <h3 class="link-title">Vacations</h3>
            <div class="link-description">Let's take some vacations!</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

No matter what I try, I can't seem to override the `<a>` on hover, which is underlining everything:

I want the `<a>` to behave like this for all elements *except* the "link-description" as seen above.
Any ideas?

```css
:not ( ).....;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is a CSS selector like `a:hover .link-title` what you are looking for?

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer
}

a:hover .link-title,
a:active .link-title,
a:focus .link-title {
  text-decoration: underline
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="spalink" title="">
        <div class="link-container">
            <div class="link-image" style="background-image: url(IMAGE);"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="link-content">
            <h3 class="link-title">Vacations</h3>
            <div class="link-description">Let's take some vacations!</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```